# Time Picker Control ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, user-controls, web-controls

I was doing an ASP.Net Web Page application. As a part of the same it is required to implement Time Picker control to select time between which some users can log in (to implement time shift and verification during login).

While searching, I could not find a ASP TimePicker control. Please quide me how to implement some time picker controls. Also, which data type should be used in SQL Server to save the same without any format mismatches.

Comment: http://www.michaelkbell.com/TimePicker/ check this

Comment: Seems implementable. I will try to implement and revert.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.time, new  {@class = "form-control timepicker-holdOffTime",type = "time",step = 1})
```